# Identify SWT and JFace widgets on picture

Tags: java, swt, jface, mockups

I created this mockup (see below), using the usual java look and feel, which I know as user.
Now I want to implement this mockup, by using SWT, JFace, Eclipse RCP.

Notes:

The NVV/RMV/KVG/RKH on the left should behave according to the [accordion pattern](http://www.normansblog.de/demos/simple-jquery-accordion/)
The Tabs NVV, RMV, KVG are parent Tabs of Module, Manage Layouts Tabs. 
The Tree Menu on the left opens Tabs on the right

**Questions:**

- Which SWT/ JFace Classes should I use, to implement this mockup?
- Do you see any problems in this mockup? (regarding different Implementation, usability etc.)

[image: Mockup]

Comment: You have that NVV/RMV... headers on the left side. What should be their behaviour?

Comment: The NVV/RMV/KVG/RKH should behave according to the accordion pattern, as implemented here: http://www.normansblog.de/demos/simple-jquery-accordion/

Comment: ExpandBar is for you then. It is not resizing itself though.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not resizing itself" ?

Comment: The accordion you showed me is changing its height. The ExpandBar's height is precalculated as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, you mean the JS implementation :) I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the widgets you specified are readily available in the Eclipse RCP framework.

First of all you should check out some tutorials here: [vogella tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html)

In addition to that I strongly advise you to use WindowBuilder so you can design GUIs rather easily: [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)

For the tab folders (NVV/RMV...) on the top you can use `TabFolder` and `TabItem` like this:

```
     tabFolder_1 = new TabFolder(this, SWT.NONE);
     tbtmNvv = new TabItem(tabFolder_1, SWT.NONE);
     tbtmNvv.setText("NVV");
     tbtmRmv = new TabItem(tabFolder_1, SWT.NONE);
     tbtmRmv.setText("RMV");
```

`this` stands for the parent `Composite` in my code. `TabFolder`s work by placing a `Control` inside them just don't forget to call the `setControl` method to make its content visible. `TabFolder`s can be nested into each other. Alternatively you can use RCP View-s for your top level tabs.

For the table in the middle you can use JFace components namely the `TableViewer` like this:

```
    tableViewer = new TableViewer(tabFolder_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    tbtmRmv.setControl(table);

    tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnMyCol = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
    tblclmnMyCol.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnMyCol.setText("My col");
```

If you want to know how to bind data to your tables you should check out the tutorials I mentioned above.

For accordions you can use the `ExpandBar` like this:

```
    expandBar = new ExpandBar(this, SWT.NONE);

    xpndtmItem = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
    xpndtmItem.setText("Item 1");

    xpndtmItem_1 = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
    xpndtmItem_1.setText("Item2");
```

or a TreeViewer:

```
    treeViewer = new TreeViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    tree = treeViewer.getTree();
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    tree.setLinesVisible(true);
```

You can also place `TreeViewer`s in your `ExpandBar`.

As for the layout I usually stick with `GridLayout` which is a good all-rounder.

Briefing you on how to use those components/layouts is out of the scope of an SO answer I'm afraid, but you can always check the tutorials I linked, they will help you in your endeavours in Eclipse RCP.